# IIS Redirect URL Query String to lowercase

Tags: url, redirect, iis, tolower

I have the redirect for the URL portion working, but the Query String is not changed.
How do I redirect the ENTIRE URL to lower case?
https://dummyURL.com?Query=FOO  to
https://dummyurl.com?query=foo

Currently I have this:

```
<rule name="Convert to lower case" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url=".*[A-Z].*" ignoreCase="false" />
  <action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{R:0}}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Any assistance would be most helpful
This is a Windows 10 application and is a showstopper

Answer (score 0):

You can use this example as a reference:

```
<rule name="URL Lower" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />                        
    <conditions trackAllCaptures="true">
      <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="(.*)" /> 
      <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern=".*[A-Z].*" ignoreCase="false" />
    </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{URL}}?{ToLower:{C:0}}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Perfect.  Exactly what I needed.  Thank you for the help

Comment: I'm so glad this helps you. It is so appreciated if you can mark solution as answer.